# Override method without changing any original code

Tags: java, class, methods, overriding

I have a Main class, an X class and a Z class.

X has the method a().

Z has the method b().

Main calls the method b() in Z and then the method a() in X.

Then I have my class X2 with its method a2().

Is it possible, without changing Main or X, to force Main to use method a2() from X2 instead of a() from X, through Z's b() method?

Comment: Why don't you *show* us the code instead of *describing* it?

Comment: So why you don't just replace the method call in Z.b() from a() to a2()?

Comment: The answer to your question is "No" And I'm assuming when you say "change" you are referring to changing the source or changing the class as loaded with omething like AspectJ or other byte-code instrumentation tool.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it, since the Main class still create an instance of X `X x = new X()`.

The only way to have the Main class invoke a method that overrides `X.a()` is if you change the call in Main to `X x = new X2()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then yes if Z is responsible for creating the X, and X2 extends X.  This is called polymorphism.  Consider this example:

```
public class X {
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("X.a");
    }
}

public class X2 extends X {
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("X2.a");
    }
}

public class Z {
    private X my_x;
    public Z() {
        this.my_x = new X2();
    }

    public X getX() {
        return my_x;
    }

    public void b() {
        System.out.println("Z.b");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Z z = new Z();
        X x = z.getX();
        z.b();
        x.a();  // this prints. X2.a
    }
}
```